# Switching the mod key isn't working for me in i3

Tags: i3-wm

When I started my *i3*, I set the <kbd>super</kbd> key for my mod key. It was fine for a few hours, but then when I was messing around with `lxappearance`, `gtk-chtheme`, and `qt4-qtconfig`, my mod key somehow got switched to the <kbd>alt</kbd> key after I reloaded i3.

The `config/i3/config` file says `set $mod Mod4` so I don't know why my kbd>alt key is still selected as my mod key.

Comment: I'm using Linux/Ubuntu

Comment: I have just the opposite problem. The mod key is always the Windows key no matter what I change in the config file. `bindsym Mod1+Return exec i3-sensible-terminal` and `bindsym Mod4+Return exec i3-sensible-terminal` makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty old but just in case anyone else struggles with this, I had the same issue and I finally figured out that the config file in my user folder (/home/me/.config/i3/config was overriding /etc/i3/config

Comment: It seems like i3 is ignoring whatever's in my config file. The mod key is always the Windows key no matter what I do. Even after setting it using i3-config-wizard.

Comment: Not sure I am able to help, but I'll try. The .config directory ( the dot at the beginning is impoprtant) in your user directory is hidden by default, both in nautilus and terminal, but you will see it if you do ls -a in terminal.   

From your home directory, in a terminal, you need to enter something along the lines of   
```
sudo nano .config/i3/config
```  
and make the changes there to the set $mod line. I hope that helps!